# How do I add a marker only at the end of a dynamic highchart?

Tags: highcharts

I have a line chart which dynamically updates. I want to add a marker at the last point. As the chart scrolls and new points are added, I want to remove the previous marker and add it to the most recent point. Thus the "tip" of this line chart will only have a marker.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: By markers do you mean something similar to the flags used in highstocks? http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/flags-placement

Answer (score 4):

You can disable markers in the plotOptions, and then for the point that you want the marker to appear on, set the data as an object, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/JVNjs/281/

```
data: [7,12,16,32,{y:64,marker:{enabled:true,radius:5,fillColor:'#c00'}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable marker for each point except the last one.

On start:

```
  series: [{
    name: 'Random data',
    data: (function () {
        // generate an array of random data
        var data = [],
            time = (new Date()).getTime(),
            i;

        for (i = -19; i <= 0; i += 1) {
            data.push({
                x: time + i * 1000,
                y: Math.random(),
                marker: {
                  enabled: i === 0
                }
            });
        }
        return data;
    }())
}]
```

And disabling marker in the last point before the new point is added:

```
      events: {
        load: function () {

            // set up the updating of the chart each second
            var series = this.series[0];
            setInterval(function () {
                var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                    y = Math.random();
                series.data[series.data.length - 1].update({
                  marker: { enabled: false }
                }, false)
                series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
```

You could try this.
http://jsfiddle.net/687215jj/2/